Is it correct to say "tell your grandma that you had your hair washed today already so you don't have to do it tomorrow"?
May daughter has long hair and she has her hair washed by her mom 3 times a week or every 2 days.
Say, today she had her hair washed by her mom already. She is going to her grandma's home tomorrow. Her grandma will give her a shower but not wash her hair tomorrow there. She has to let her grandma know that.
Is it correct for me to say this today?
"tell your grandma that you had your hair washed today already so you don't have to do it tomorrow"?

Don't suppose that there is one and only one way to express yourself.
Don't forget that "grandma" is (presumably) a native speaker of English and is quite capable of asking questions.
Your daughter is also (presumably) capable of conversation.  (if these assumptions are not true, then don't use English)
There's no problem in your expression.  But you are trying to speak as if you are writing, and trying to get all the information in one go.  "Tell grandma not to wash your hair." is fine. If grandma wants to know why she can ask and daughter can answer, in the normal manner of a conversation.

I see no problem with the statement as given, grammatically or etiquette-ally. It's the sort of thing I absolutely would say to my young child as I sent them off to grandma's.
